# jQuery each() doesn't iterate on all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stared too long on this apparently not working little piece of code. Why doesn't select box rel attribute get alerted?

HTML:

```
<select rel="prop216" name="prop[]">
  <option value="">- none</option>
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
</select>
<select rel="prop217" name="prop[]">
  <option value="">- none</option>
  <option value="12">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="13">Opt 2</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$("select").change(function()
{
 var i = 0;
 var alteredSelects = [];
 $("select").each(function()
 {
    if ( $(this).val() !== "" )
    {
        alteredSelects[i][0] = $(this).attr('rel');
        alteredSelects[i][1] = $(this).val();
        alert ($(this).attr('rel'));
        i++;

    }
 });
});
```

See also my jSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ft6Bd/1/

I get an error in Firefox

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

on the line `alteredSelects[i][0] = $(this).attr('rel');`

But can't seem to realize why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first have to initialize `alteredSelects[i]` before you can assign values to it:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var alteredSelects = [];
    $("select").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).val() !== "" ) {
            alteredSelects[i] = []; // <-- Initialize `alteredSelects[i]` as empty array.
            alteredSelects[i][0] = $(this).attr('rel');
            alteredSelects[i][1] = $(this).val();
            alert($(this).attr('rel'));
            i++;
        }
    });
});
```

The problem was that you were trying to save something to `alteredSelects[i]`, while `alteredSelects[i]` was `null`.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the answer, but you shouldn't use own declarated variable for indexing:
jquery each has got own Index:

```
  $.each(collection, function(index, value) { 

  });
```

Comment: I also thought about that but in his case, he needs a custom counter because not all the selects will be equal to "". So he'll end up having empty values in his array.

Comment: But that gives me indexes for all select elements, I only need them for the ones that is set...

Comment: It might not be correct in this case, but it's a good suggestion.

Comment: Ok, You are right. I haven't seen, it's increased only when the condition is true. Apology :)